# Alternator Connector Type Mazda Miata / Nissan

Tags: connector

I am trying to identify the connector type for this alternator rectifier part n. 1360e500.
The terminal blades are 6.3mm "spades"


[image: alternator] [image: 1360e500]

Comment: What does your car automotive manual say about the parts? Have you tried searching for the part number you have given in your question? Who makes it? Is it an automotive alternator? Have you tried contacting the supplier of the alternator?

Comment: Oh boy. That's an automotive connector. They are a challenge.

Ask these guys: https://connectorexperts.com/ or these guys: https://www.automotiveconnectors.com/

Or, go to the parts department for the dealer for that brand of vehicle and they'll sell you a connector with wire tails already in it.

Comment: Didn't know about connectorexperts.com, great resource. Thanks for the tip Davide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook group Motorsport Wiring Alliance found it.


yazaki 58 X series for mazda miata (gues "the answer is always miata" hahaha)

https://www.bmotorsports.com/shop/product_info.php/products_id/5180?fbclid=IwAR2WhzqdO81fc3h7iKszGD_5BxV-CIdXRK55vuIpkhRLAOYF0owLRHEqLKE

Thanks for your help.